# How can I change the CSS (BG Color) of a specific element with JavaScript Hover events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, background

Please be patient with me, as I am a fairly new programmer and am extremely unfamiliar with client-side programming. This is my first live project and I wish to do quite a few things that I do not have the knowledge of.

The page in question can be found at http://paysonfirstassembly.com/

I am attempting to accomplish a fairly simple task. I need to change the background color of a specific element (Can be referred to by ID, of course) when it is hovered over. I know that there are other methods of doing this, but frankly, my brain is fried from being sick.

Also, if it helps, I AM using JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use CSS, not jQuery for things like this.

In your stylesheet, just add a `:hover` selector to the CSS style of an element. This new style deceleration gets rendered when the element is hovered:

```
#original_element {
  background-color: blue;
}

#original_element:hover, .hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

To support those poor people with IE6 and JS (this works for those without JS too), you can use a jQuery function:

```
$('#original_element').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');  
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was unaware that CSS had such a property!

Comment: @Blender: Is this now cross-browser compatible solution for ANY html element?

Comment: It's always best to use CSS when possible. but `:hover` doesn't work in IE6, since you're already using jQuery, it makes sense to use jQuery's hover for cross browser support

Comment: @Hussein: While that is a valid point, I will use CSS solely because I am personally unaware of a machine with IE6 installed. :P Not to mention the number of machines I am aware of with IE installed... Except at the school, haha.

Comment: Oh, and a possible fix for IE6. It's a bit overkill, but hey, if it works it works: http://www.danvega.org/blog/index.cfm/2008/1/1/CSS-hover-selector

Comment: @Penumbra allot of people worldwide still use IE6, specially elders and non tech savvy users. It's always wise to cover IE6,  That's why jQuery is great.

Comment: I agree. Maybe using *both* solutions, one for people with JS, and one for those without? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Blender: That would be the safe way :)

Comment: I was also considering using both solutions. Given the time frame of my project, the implementation of such will depend on how much coding I get done in the next couple of weeks! (Insert plug here about my newest question that you all may answer if you wish. :D)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(ELEMENT).hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    },
    function(){
        // this is for 'mouse-out' event
    }
);
```

Btw: It's better to assign css class, that has that background color set (+ any additional styles), then you can do this:

```
$(ELEMENT).hover(
    function(){
        // add your css class to hovered element
        $(this).addClass('highlightClass');
    },
    function(){
        // this is for 'mouse-out' event
        // and we are going to remove that highlight
        $(this).removeClass('highlightClass');
    }
);
```

Css class could be:

```
.highlightClass {background-color:yellow;}
```

Comment: Oh my lord I love this community. Such fast answers! :D Are you aware of what the mouse-out event would happen to be using jquery?

Comment: @Penumbra: Haha, me too :) I edited my answer to show you example how to use that mouseout part.

Comment: Fantastic, so the part of the .hover function after the comma is like passing in a second parameter which jquery recognizes as the mouseout event? Also, does anything special need to be done to have two CSS classes on one element?

Comment: @Penumbra: Yes, you could say it like that probably :) You can have any number of class on element.

Answer (score 1):

You may look for this:

```
$(selector).hover(
    function() { $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); },
    function() { $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'blue')
}, function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red')
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/KW5mJ/